# Tem como iniciar um Select (SQL) na metade da tabela de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-select

Amigos, existe alguma forma dentro da linguagem SQL (e usando BD mysql) onde eu posso iniciar um Select na metade de uma tabela?

Por exemplo, tenho 500 endereços na tabela. Faço uma busca pelos endereços do Bairro X (where bairro="x"), reduzindo o total para, digamos, 60 endereços. Mas eu queria começar a listagem a partir da metade desses 60 em diante, ignorando os anteriores (mesmo sendo eles tambem do bairro "x"). Tem como?

Outra questão é que eu não sei quantos valores terei dependendo do bairro selecionado, então pode variar. 60, 68, 90 etc. Existe alguma função dentro do SQL que faça a listagem do Select iniciar na metade (ou em qualquer ponto, por exemplo, 1/3, 2/3, 5/6 etc) de um resultado de select+where?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Quais as colunas que tem nessa tabela?

Comment: tem , use o having com count... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Na verdade são várias colunas. Eu coloquei este exemplo de endereços apenas para facilitar a explicação do que eu estou buscando. Ficou estranho querer ignorar alguns endereços ne? hahaha

É uma tabela com dicas. Então dependendo das variáveis do Where, a pessoa receberia algumas dicas. Mas nao quero colocar Rand() pq nao quero que a pessoa fique dando reload na página para receber dicas diferentes a cada reload.

Comment: Algo como, por exemplo.
"Select * from dicas where idade>50 AND Sexo=1 COMANDOX 1/2 Order By TipoDica"

... este COMANDO 1/2 é q nao sei o q seria, se existe, se conseguiria fazer isso pra mim, de começar a listagem desse select a partir da metade que ele encontrou com suas condições Where.

Comment: Marconcilio... agora entendi melhor sua sugestão! Vou tentar! Obrigado!!!

Comment: O having count nao adiantou. No exemplo que citei no meu comentário acima, por exemplo, eu nao sei onde eu poderia colocar ele pra iniciar a partir de algum ponto da listagem.

Answer (score 3):

Usando `LIMIT` e `OFFSET`

Mostrar 10 registros começando do primeiro:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA LIMIT 0, 10
```

Mostrar 10 registros começando do décimo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA LIMIT 10, 10
```

Mostrar 32 registros começando do 45°:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA LIMIT 45, 32
```

Comment: Não é uma boa opção: LIMIT 10000, 20 significa que ele vai ler 100020 e jogar fora 10000  para retornar 20 linhas.

Comment: Vou testar. Talvez funcione. Eu ja uso o Limit 10 pq quero mostrar apenas 10 resultados. O desafio aí seria eu conseguir saber o total que o Where vai me retornar, para entao definir a partir de onde esse Limit 10 vai iniciar a busca. Mas acho que é o mais proximo do que eu busco. Se nao der certo, vou ver se arrumo solução no php mesmo. Pego toda a listagem que vier da condição Where e depois via loop no php eu começo a mostrar so a partir da metade do total.

Comment: Essa é a melhor opção caso queira fazer paginação (é o que me parece). Para saber o total de registros faça um SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABELA, aí você poderá via código repartir a quantidade de páginas a depender da quantidade de registros por página.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode indexar os resultados em ordem crescente e depois pegar apenas os registros que forem maior que a metade do total dos registros encontrados:

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, @i := @i + 1
  AS num
  FROM tabela
  ORDER BY bairro, id
) AS t
WHERE num > (
  SELECT
  COUNT(produto) - (COUNT(produto) / 2)
  FROM tabela
  WHERE bairro = 'x'
)
AND bairro = 'x';
```

Onde `id` é o *primary index* e `x` é o código do "bairro".

Por exemplo:

Se for encontrado 6 registros, o `WHERE num >` irá pegar apenas os registros com `num` maior que a metade, ou seja, do 4 até o 6 (3 registros).

```
----------------------
| id | bairro  | num |
----------------------
| 11 | bairroX |  1  |
----------------------
| 14 | bairroY |  2  |
----------------------
| 18 | bairroX |  3  |
----------------------
| 21 | bairroZ |  4  | ←
----------------------
| 35 | bairroA |  5  | ←
----------------------
| 39 | bairroF |  6  | ←
----------------------
```

Se quiser pegar a 1/3 parte do resultado, basta alterar o `2` em `COUNT(produto) - (COUNT(produto) / 2)` para `3`; a quarta parte, `4`, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

Quando o procedimento é algo mais complexo, podemos trabalhar com `procedure` para não precisar ficar criando `variáveis globais` e acabar não retornando o resultado esperado, assim teremos uma execução completa do bloco de instruções criados na `PROCEDURE`.
Nessa `procedure` setamos o valor da variavei inicio na metade dos registros da tabela e pegamos até o final dela(que é a quantidade total de registros) para testar só alterar a tag `[tabela]` e criar a `procedure`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_get_bairros;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_bairros()
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_inicio INT;
    DECLARE v_fim INT;

    SELECT
            COUNT(*)
    INTO v_fim
    FROM [tabela];

    SET v_inicio = v_fim / 2;

    SELECT
        *
    FROM [tabela]
    LIMIT v_inicio, v_fim;


END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Logo após a criação, é só chamar da seguinte forma `CALL sp_get_bairros()`

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html